# How to use execCommand to set a new line?

Tags: javascript, dom, execcommand

I want to insert a line break and set the caret position in the new line.

I have this

```
<!-- editable -->
<div>
    hello
</div>
```

Then I add a new line

```
document.execCommand("insertHtml", false, "world" + "<br> ");
```

But the caret is not moved after the `<br>`, so when I type the text doesn't go to the new line.

How can I set the caret position in the new line so when I type it goes bellow?

Actual result:

```
helloworld<typedtext>
```

Expected result:

```
helloworld
<typedtext>
```

**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DqGk/)**

Tested on Chrome 15

Comment: that's working for me but no in ie9, http://jsfiddle.net/BhZzu/

Comment: It works for me on Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 4):

just add a line break and it will move it in chrome
so some thing like this

```
document.execCommand("insertHtml", false, "world");
document.execCommand('insertParagraph',false);
```

Question was asked a while ago but hope it helps someone anyway

Answer (score 3):

```
document.execCommand('insertText', true, 'hi\\r\\nworld')
```

Comment: according to my experiences it is better to pass newlines only as '\n' instead of '\r\n', at least on Chrome.
If you need to insert blank line, '\r\n\r\n' will create and empty <div></div>,  but '\r\n\r\n' creates <div><br/></div>